# how to check each tag value is different from value present in other tag with same name

Tags: xml, jmeter

inn jmeter ,In a xml response with multiple same name's tag , how to validate that each  value present in tag  is different from each other on Jmeter.I have attached the response which has to be validated .This code contain description of 2 offers ,but this number can vary from 0-10. I want to put a unique check on "msgid" (i.e no msgid value is same in the response) and also give a count of number of times msgid tag is repeated in the response .

```
enter code here <offers>
           <number xsi:nil="true"/>
           <number>
              <amrit>S</amrit>
              <interestedFlag>Y</interestedFlag>
              <msgid>145983</msgid>
              <msisdn xsi:nil="true"/>                 
              <offerIndex>1</offerIndex>
              <msgtext>Rs115=225 </msgtext>
              <onlineFulfilmentFlag>Y</onlineFulfilmentFlag>
              <orderId xsi:nil="true"/>
              <otherSearchInfo>
                 <number>
                    <key>START_DATE</key>
                    <value>2016-09-16 11:28:46.921455</value>
                 </number>
                 <number>
                    <key>END_DATE</key>
                    <value>2017-08-03 00:00:00.0</value>
                 </number>
                 <number>
                    <key>OFFER_CATEGORY</key>
                    <value>Others</value>
                 </number>
              </otherSearchInfo>
              <price>115</price>
              <shortDesc>115=225Loc+STD M,28D</shortDesc>
              <subscriptionStatus>P</subscriptionStatus>
           </number>
           <number>
              <amrit>O</amrit>
              <interestedFlag>Y</interestedFlag>
              <msgid>143429</msgid>
              <msisdn xsi:nil="true"/>
              <msgid>2803708</msgid>
              <offerIndex>2</offerIndex>
              <msgtext>Rs306=Rs306 Full</msgtext>
              <onlineFulfilmentFlag>Y</onlineFulfilmentFlag>
              <orderId xsi:nil="true"/>
              <otherSearchInfo>
                 <number>
                    <key>START_DATE</key>
                    <value>2016-09-16 11:28:46.921455</value>
                 </number>
                 <number>
                    <key>END_DATE</key>
                    <value>2017-08-03 00:00:00.0</value>
                 </number>
                 <number>
                    <key>OFFER_CATEGORY</key>
                    <value>Combo</value>
                 </number>
              </otherSearchInfo>
              <price>306</price>
              <shortDesc>Rs306=306TT(Ultd Val)</shortDesc>
              <subscriptionStatus>P</subscriptionStatus>
           </number>
           <number>
              <amrit>O</amrit>
              <interestedFlag>Y</interestedFlag>
              <msgid>145022</msgid>
              <msisdn xsi:nil="true"/>
              <msgid>2800482</msgid>
              <msgtext>Rs110=Rs110 Full</msgtext>
              <onlineFulfilmentFlag>Y</onlineFulfilmentFlag>
              <orderId xsi:nil="true"/>
              <otherSearchInfo>
                 <number>
                    <key>START_DATE</key>
                    <value>2016-09-16 11:28:46.921455</value>
                 </number>
                 <number>
                    <key>END_DATE</key>
                    <value>2017-08-03 00:00:00.0</value>
                 </number>
                 <number>
                    <key>OFFER_CATEGORY</key>
                    <value>Others</value>
                 </number>
              </otherSearchInfo>
              <price>110</price>
              <shortDesc>Rs110=Rs110 FTT, ULTD</shortDesc>
              <subscriptionStatus>P</subscriptionStatus>
           </number>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kill two birds with one stone using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

1. Add JSR223 Assertion as a child of the request which returns the above XML
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils
   import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate

   def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
   def msgids = xml."**".findAll { node ->
       node.name() == "msgid"
   }
   msgids.each { msgid ->
       int msgidCount = CollectionUtils.countMatches(msgids, new Predicate() {
           boolean evaluate(Object input) {
               return (input.equals(msgid));
           }
       })
       log.info("Message ID: " + msgid + " count: " + msgidCount) 
       if (msgidCount > 1) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Message ID " + msgid + " occurred " + msgidCount + " times")
       }

   }
   log.info("msgid count: " + msgids.size())
   ```

   - If there will be a duplicate `msgid` tag the assertion will fail the sampler and provide tag value and the number of occurrences in the message
   - Number of occurrences of each `msgid` tag will be printed to *jmeter.log* file

     [image: JMeter JSR223 Assertion XML]

References:

- [Processing XML - Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)